# Command works at the command-line, but won't work in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

I am creating a script and when I try to capture a command return, I have an error of command not found, if I use this command on the terminal:

```
gcloud -q compute snapshots list --format='csv(NAME)'
```

It works fine.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
CSV_SNAPSHOTS= $(gcloud -q compute snapshots list --format='csv(NAME)')
IFS=$'\n'

for i in $CSV_SNAPSHOTS
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: I don't think you want glob expansion on the words resulting of the splitting of `$CSV_SNAPSHOTS`, so you should probably issue a `set -o noglob` before that `for` loop.

Comment: Depending on what's at /bin/sh (If it's an actual Bourne shell, for instance) the modern $(command) metaphor may not even be supported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There must not be any whitespace after `=` (and also before `=`) in variable declaration.

So this should do:

```
CSV_SNAPSHOTS=$(gcloud -q compute snapshots list --format='csv(NAME)')
```

Also note that, you should (almost always) quote variable and command substitution, although you would get away in this case as you are saving the command substitution to a variable.

---

**Example:**

```
$ foo="$(echo spam)"
$ echo "$foo"
spam

$ bar= "$(echo egg)"
No command 'egg' found, did you mean:
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is the space after the `=`, but you could also bypass storing the output in a variable and instead read it directly into your loop:

```
IFS=$'\n'

gcloud -q compute snapshots list --format='csv(NAME)' |
while read -r i; do
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```